# Apply def function to a dataframe recursively

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, recursion, user-defined-functions

I am trying to calculate the column values of Cat "recursively"

Every loop should calculate the Cat columns max value (Catz) of a group of x. If the Date range becomes <=60, Cat column value should be updated with Catz +=1. I got an arcpy of this process going. I, however, have thousands of other data sets outside that need not be converted in arcpy friendly format. I am not well familiar with pandas.

Made reference to [1]: [Calculate DataFrame values recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43710057/calculate-dataframe-values-recursively) and  [2]: [python pandas- apply function with two arguments to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34279378/python-pandas-apply-function-with-two-arguments-to-columns) . I still havent quite understood the Series/Dataframe Concept and how to apply either outcome

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta
import time
from datetime import date
dict = {'x':["ASPELBJNMI", "JUNRNEXCRG", "ASPELBJNMI", "JUNRNEXCRG"], 
        'start': ["6/27/2018", "8/4/2018", "8/22/2018", "8/12/2018"], 
        'finish':["8/11/2018", "10/3/2018", "8/31/2018", "10/26/2018"],
        'DateRange':[0,0,0,0],
        'Cat':[-1,-1,-1,-1],
        'ID':[1,2,3,4]} 

df = pd.DataFrame(dict)

df.set_index('ID')
def classd(houp):
    Catz = houp.Cat.min()
    Catz +=1

    houp  = houp.groupby('x')
    for x, houp2 in houp:


        houp.DateRange  = (pd.to_datetime(houp.finish.loc[:]).min()- houp.start.loc[:]).astype('timedelta64[D]')

    houp.Cat = np.where(houp.DateRange<=60, Catz , -1)
    return houp

df['Cat'] =  df[['x','DateRange','Cat']].apply(classd, axis=1).Cat
print df
```

I get the following Traceback when I run my code

Catz = houp.Cat.min()
AttributeError: ("'long' object has no attribute 'min'", u'occurred at index 0')

Desired outcome

```
   OBJECTID_1 * Conc *  ID  start   finish  DateRange   Cat
1   ASPELBJNMI  LAPMT   6/27/2018   8/11/2018   45  0
2   ASPELBJNMI  KLKIY   8/22/2018   8/31/2018   9   1
15  JUNRNEXCRG  CGCHK   8/4/2018    10/3/2018   60  1
16  JUNRNEXCRG  IQYGJ   8/12/2018   10/26/2018  83  -1
```

Answer (score 0):

You program is little bit complecated to comprehend

But i would suggest to try something simple with apply function:

```
s.apply(lambda x: x ** 2)
```

here `s` is a series

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html